# How to get Clangd working properly with VS Code on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, clang, clang++

I can't get clangd to provide autocompletion for any external headers like from SFML.

I have tried doing the same on an Ubuntu VM and everything worked properly. The compile_commands.json has been moved to the project root aswell.

The project tree looks like this right now:

```
.clangd
--index
----main.cpp.1B607D111B8CF0BE.idx

build
--CMakeFiles etc

src
--main.cpp

CMakeLists.txt

compile_commands.json
```

The CMakeLists.txt contains this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

set(src_files
    src/main.cpp)

set(SFML_DIR "D:/Libs/SFML/SFML-2.5.1-windows-vc15-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/lib/cmake/SFML/")

find_package(SFML COMPONENTS graphics)

add_executable(test ${src_files})

target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE sfml-graphics)

target_include_directories(test PRIVATE D:/Libs/SFML/SFML-2.5.1-windows-vc15-64-bit/SFML-2.5.1/include)
```

The compile_commands.json contains this:

```
[
{
  "directory": "C:/Users/Joerg/projects/test/build",
  "command": "C:\\PROGRA~1\\LLVM\\bin\\CLANG_~1.EXE   @CMakeFiles/test.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -Xclang -gcodeview -O0 -D_DEBUG -D_DLL -D_MT -Xclang --dependent-lib=msvcrtd   -std=gnu++17 -o CMakeFiles\\test.dir\\src\\main.cpp.obj -c C:\\Users\\Joerg\\projects\\test\\src\\main.cpp",
  "file": "C:/Users/Joerg/projects/test/src/main.cpp"
}
]
```

I have also tried using MinGW Clang where the corresponding compile_commands.json looked like this:

```
[
{
  "directory": "C:/Users/Joerg/projects/test/build nin",
  "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\clang++.exe      -std=gnu++17 -o CMakeFiles\\test.dir\\src\\main.cpp.obj -c C:\\Users\\Joerg\\projects\\test\\src\\main.cpp",
  "file": "C:/Users/Joerg/projects/test/src/main.cpp"
}
]
```

I expect clangd to provide autocompletion for the SFML namespace (sf::) as it does for the std namespace (std::). Currently it does not find the Header as it should when I write `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>`. It gives me this error message: 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found clang(pp_file_not_found)

Answer (score 1):

I got `clangd` to work on Visual Studio Code with the `mingw-w64` compiler, `CMAKE`, and `SFML` by doing the following:

1. Install the `clangd` extension in Visual Studio Code.
2. `CMAKE` must create the `compile_commands.json` file. This is done via `set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)`, which you already described.
3. Create a `.clangd` file in the root folder of your project.
4. Add the following to the `.clangd` file:

   ```
   CompileFlags:
     Add: [
       --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32,
     ]
   ```
5. At this point, you might have to restart Visual Studio Code. It should now recognize SFML as well as the mingw standard library header files.

Comment: If you install Clangd from MSYS2 (along with the compiler), you don't have to mess with `--target`.

Answer (score 0):

clangd uses compile_commands.json to get include properties, but clang version under 10.0 doesn't recognize .rsp files such as `@CMakeFiles/test.dir/includes_CXX.rsp`. That's why your clangd can't find certain header files.